# Installing laminate splashback on top of old tiles

Tags: drywall, kitchens, laminate, backsplash

I’m installing a new IKEA kitchen, including a laminate splashback. Various people in forums and also a kitchen installer I got advice from are suggesting that the tiles should be removed before installing the new splashback. I’m removing the tiles from the walls which are only partly tiled (there are two small areas like this), as the edge will be visible and I don’t want to be able to see the combined thickness of the old tiles and new splashback.

For the wall behind the worktop, there will be no visible edge so the only problem that I can see is that we’ll loose 10mm so of space in the room by not removing the old tiles. If I keep the old tiles they will be roughed up to ensure a good bond to the new splashback.

I’m reluctant to go to all the effort of removing tiles and replacing the plasterboard wall if it’s not necessary.

Am I missing something? Why is it commonly recommended to remove the old tiles?

Comment: Because the correct way to do tings is to do them properly. If you want to cut corners, you can do so. But if in the future you decide to update the kitchen again, say in 10 years, you will have to deal with two layers.

Comment: Putting a backsplash up if just laminate it will look like crap and that is a polite way of saying it.  if you value the resale on your home do it right as anm767 and upvotes confirm. I would rather have dated tile than poorly done cheap laminate.

Comment: Why do you say it look crap? The full wall, from countertop to underside of cabinets, and from wall to wall will be covered, so no edges will be visible.

Comment: Ed Beal, your comment is interesting as you a demonstrating the problem I have. Nobody seems capable of explaining *why* it would be advisable to remove the tiles. It’s clear that this is a common viewpoint but I am yet to see someone articulate a reason that they hold this view. I don’t disagree that it may be the best thing to do, I am seeking to understand *why* it is the best thing to do.